# Testing for equality in Realm

Tags: ios, swift, testing, realm

I'm trying to test for equality among `Realm` objects in unit tests.  However, I'm unable to get objects to return `true` for their equality.

According to the [Realm docs here](https://realm.io/docs/swift/1.0.2/#injecting-realm-instances), I should be able to do that:

```
let expectedUser = User()
expectedUser.email = "help@realm.io"
XCTAssertEqual(testRealm.objects(User.self).first!,
               expectedUser,
               "User was not properly updated from server.")
```

However, I get the following test failure with the following code:

**Realm Model**

```
class Blurb: Object {
    dynamic var text = ""
}
```

**Test**

```
func testRealmEquality() {
    let a = Blurb()
    a.text = "asdf"
    let b = Blurb()
    b.text = "asdf"
    XCTAssertEqual(a, b)
}
```

> XCTAssertEqual failed: ("Optional(Blurb {
>       text = asdf;
>   })") is not equal to ("Optional(Blurb {
>       text = asdf;
>   })")

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Katsumi from Realm here. Realm object's `Equatable` is implemented as follows:

```
BOOL RLMObjectBaseAreEqual(RLMObjectBase *o1, RLMObjectBase *o2) {
    // if not the correct types throw
    if ((o1 && ![o1 isKindOfClass:RLMObjectBase.class]) || (o2 && ![o2 isKindOfClass:RLMObjectBase.class])) {
        @throw RLMException(@"Can only compare objects of class RLMObjectBase");
    }
    // if identical object (or both are nil)
    if (o1 == o2) {
        return YES;
    }
    // if one is nil
    if (o1 == nil || o2 == nil) {
        return NO;
    }
    // if not in realm or differing realms
    if (o1->_realm == nil || o1->_realm != o2->_realm) {
        return NO;
    }
    // if either are detached
    if (!o1->_row.is_attached() || !o2->_row.is_attached()) {
        return NO;
    }
    // if table and index are the same
    return o1->_row.get_table() == o2->_row.get_table()
        && o1->_row.get_index() == o2->_row.get_index();
}
```

In summary, a) if both objects are unmanaged, it works same as normal object's `Equatable`. b) if both objects are managed, if they are the same table (class) and index, they are equal. c) If one is managed, another is unmanaged, ther are not equal.

"managed" means the object has stored in Realm.

So `a` and `b` in your code is not equal. Because `a` and `b` are unmanaged (have not stored in Realm) and they are different objects.

```
let a = Blurb()
a.text = "asdf"
let b = Blurb()
b.text = "asdf"
XCTAssertEqual(a.text, b.text)
```

Furthermore, when testing the equality, Realm doesn't care the values of the objects. Realm checks only a table and row index (as mentioned "b)"). Because different objects that has the same value are stored in the database is normal.

2023 Edit - the below is only true if the object has a primary key, so the `Blurb` object would need to be defined as

```
class Blurb: Object {
    @Persisted(primaryKey: true) var _id: ObjectId
    @Persisted var text = ""
}
```

An example that two objects are equal is like the following:

```
let a = Blurb()
a.text = "asdf"

let realm = try! Realm()
try! realm.write {
    realm.add(a)
}

let b = realm.objects(Blurb.self).first!
print(a == b) // true
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. However, in the realm docs code example, isn't expectedUser an unmanaged object which just has the same email property value? Why should that test ever pass?

Comment: @solidcell Sorry for the confusion. I think the document is not correct or something is omitted for simplicity. I'll fix the issue of the document soon, thanks for pointing out!

Comment: Has this behavior changed? It looks like at least as of Realm 3.7.4, `Equatable` only works on objects with primary keys; when I try a similar create/add/retrieve cycle as above on a class with no primary key, I get `isSameObject(as:)` returning true, but `isEqual()` returning false.

Answer (score -4):

Do you know how comparison protocols works on iOS?

If you don't, check here
http://nshipster.com/swift-comparison-protocols/

Basically if you do

```
let a = NSObject()
let b = NSObject()
let c = a
a == b // false
a == c // true
```

You should create a class like this conform to **Equatable**

```
class MyClass: Equatable {
  let myProperty: String

  init(s: String) {
    myProperty = s
  }
}

func ==(lhs: MyClass, rhs: MyClass) -> Bool {
  return lhs.myProperty == rhs.myProperty
}

let myClass1 = MyClass(s: "Hello")
let myClass2 = MyClass(s: "Hello")
myClass1 == myClass2 // true
myClass1 != myClass2 // false
myClass1 === myClass2 // false
myClass1 !== myClass2 // true
```

I suggest to check .text for testing

```
func testRealmEquality() {
    let a = Blurb()
    a.text = "asdf"
    let b = Blurb()
    b.text = "asdf"
    XCTAssertEqual(a.text, b.text)
}
```

Comment: Yea I know how `Equatable` works, however I'm unsure of how `Realm` implements it, nor why their docs show it apparently being able to be used to test for objects being comparable (but not the same exact object). I'd rather not have to test for every property for every object in an array if possible. That tends to get out of hand.

Comment: Last suggestion. Did you check the Realm documentation about this?
https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#testing

Comment: Yea, check out the beginning of my question and you'll see that I linked to the docs and pasted the relevant snippet already.

Comment: Yep. Sorry for the question. I checked my projects with Realm and TDD and I never compare the whole object.