# Querying for a matching array property in Realm

Tags: swift, realm

Consider the following, using Realm Swift:

```
class Shelf : Object {
    let products = List<Product>()
}
```

and

```
class Product : Object {
    let string: String = ""
    let Shelves = LinkingObjects(fromType: Shelf.self, property: "products")
}
```

Now the question is, is it possible to perform a query like:

"What are all the shelves that match EXACTLY a specific product list?" (no more, no less).

I could not find a way to compare an array.

EDIT: 
If I try doing this:

```
let results = realm.objects(Shelf.self).filter("%@ == products",products)
```

I get the error:

```
Invalid predicate: 
Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate operations
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each Realm model class inheriting from `Object` conforms to the `Equatable` protocol by default due to the fact that `Object` inherits from `NSObject`, which conforms to `Equatable`. If the elements of a `List` conform to the `Equatable` protocol, the `List` itself conforms to it as well.

Hence, you should be able to compare `List<Product>` instances by using the `==` function and you can also directly compare `Shelf` objects.

However, be aware that `Realm` overrides the `==` function, see [Realm object's Equatable is implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38877533/4667835).

If you want a custom comparison, you can override the `==` function yourself.

Edit: I don't think this can be done using `Realm`s filter method. However, if you don't mind getting an Array back as a result and not a `Result` collection, the below method can help you.

```
let searchedProducts = List([product1, product2, product3])  //these are Product instances
let results = Array(realm.objects(Shelf.self)).filter{
    if $0.products.count != searchedProducts.count {
        return false
    }
    for product in $0.products {
        if searchedProducts.index(of: product) == nil {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}
```

The above code has been tested in Playground with a similar class and returned correct results.

Comment: But if I try that I get `Key paths that include an array property must use aggregate operations`

Comment: Please include code of what you are trying to do exactly and how you are trying to do it.

Comment: So turns out this code will return `Shelf`'s that _contain_ `[product1,product2,product3]` but may contain other products as well. I want it to contain _exactly_ products1-3

Comment: Updated my answer. You just have to check that the length of the two lists is the same and return false if not. The function already only returns true if one list contains all products of the other one, so for equal length lists it already works.

Comment: Cool. The only issue is that it seems inefficient, going through all entries. I wonder if there's a better way..

Comment: How do you suppose checking if all the entries are the same without going through all of them? And it only goes through all the entries if the two lists are the same, otherwise it returns false right when checking the length of them or when finding the first non common element.

Comment: That make sense. I wonder though if some other filtering (maybe search or other) could make it more efficient, or if there's a way (extension or not) that could make it in less code using Realm.

Comment: You can always look for a better solution, this might not be the best one, but it is working and unless you have a huge Realm with hunders of thousands of entries, its performance won't make a difference.

Comment: Using a Primary key seemed like a good idea. However it would mean the key would need to represent a set of products and would need to update from time to time ...and I think that's not what primary keys are for...

Comment: I don't know how does primary keys relate to my answer. However, in general, primary keys are used to represent a Realm entry. I am not sure what you are representing using the class called `Shelf`, but if `Shelf` isn't just a temporary state, but a fixed shelf, on which Products are changing, then you should definitely stick with using primary keys. The point of primary keys is to automatically manage updating Realm entries and making sure you have no duplicate entries.