# Comparing Realm Object List

Tags: swift, compare, realm

I want to compare 2 Realm object Lists with each other to see if they are identical.
Here is what the object looks like.

```
class ScheduleRealm: Object {
let scheduleList = List<Schedule>()
}

class Schedule: Object {
dynamic var startTime : Date = Date()
dynamic var endTime : Date = Date()
dynamic var name : String = ""   
}
```

When I print the 2 list:

```
List<Schedule> (
[0] Schedule {
    startTime = 2017-07-03 16:00:00 +0000;
    endTime = 2017-07-03 18:00:00 +0000;
    name = Weights   Mon, 3 Jul 16:00 120m;
},
[1] Schedule {
    startTime = 2017-07-04 16:00:00 +0000;
    endTime = 2017-07-04 17:30:00 +0000;
    name = Weights   Tue, 4 Jul 16:00 90m;
},
[2] Schedule {
    startTime = 2017-07-10 01:30:00 +0000;
    endTime = 2017-07-10 04:30:00 +0000;
    name = Weights   Mon, 10 Jul 01:30 180m;
}
)
List<Schedule> (
[0] Schedule {
    startTime = 2017-07-03 16:00:00 +0000;
    endTime = 2017-07-03 18:00:00 +0000;
    name = Weights   Mon, 3 Jul 16:00 120m;
},
[1] Schedule {
    startTime = 2017-07-04 16:00:00 +0000;
    endTime = 2017-07-04 17:30:00 +0000;
    name = Weights   Tue, 4 Jul 16:00 90m;
},
[2] Schedule {
    startTime = 2017-07-10 01:30:00 +0000;
    endTime = 2017-07-10 04:30:00 +0000;
    name = Weights   Mon, 10 Jul 01:30 180m;
}
)
```

I have tried using '==' or 'isEqual', but even though the lists are identical it still results to a false.
What can I do to see if they are identical to one another.

Answer (score 1):

Realm overrides the == function, see [Realm object's Equatable is implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38877533/4667835).

In short, the two lists you are comparing might be considered not to be equal by Realm, because not both of them are managed lists in Realm or because they are stored in different Realms. If this is the case, you can circumvent this by making an unmanaged copy of the managed List and comparing that to the other list.

Comment: Is this still the recommended way to achieve Equitability in this case? Can you provide an example of how you suggest to create an unmanaged copy?

Comment: @NSRover yes, this is still the recommended way. To get an unmanaged object, you can use `let unmanagedObject = Object(value: existingObject)`, so to get an unmanaged List, you can do something like `let unmanagedList = List<YourObjectType>(); unmanagedList.append(contentsOf: managedList.map{Object(value: $0)})`