# Comparing realm object list with another realm object list of same kind in swift

Tags: ios, swift, hashmap, realm, hashtable

There are two realm object lists, one of them is managed realm object and another one is unmanaged realm object.

I referred these links [Comparing realm object list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45165526/comparing-realm-object-list) and [Testing for equality](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868686/testing-for-equality-in-realm/38877533#38877533) but no luck

My realm object looks like this

```
@objcMembers
class MetaData: Object, Codable {
dynamic var label: String?
dynamic var category: String?
var value = List<Value>()
}

@objcMembers
class Value: Object, Codable {
dynamic var key: String?
dynamic var val: String?
}
```

Here is the realm object used for comparison

```
[0] MetaData {
        label = home;
        category = Address;
        value = List<Value> <0x61000010f5d0> (
            [0] Value {
                key = street;
                val = 1001  Leavenworth Street;
            },
            [1] Value {
                key = country;
                val = USA;
            },
            [2] Value {
                key = city;
                val = Sausalito;
            },
            [3] Value {
                key = state;
                val = CA;
            },
            [4] Value {
                key = postalCode;
                val = 94965;
            }
        );
    },
```

I tried overriding equality and hashValue which gives me false even though object lists are same. Any suggestions for comparing?