# Check if Realm list property contains all elements of another list

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I'm working with iOS/Swift and Realm and I've got a couple of Realm models defined like this:

```
class Message: Object {

    // other properties removed for brevity

    var recipients = List<User>()
    var acknowledgedBy = List<User>()

    @objc dynamic var fullyAcknowledged = false
}

class User: Object {

    @objc dynamic var id: Int = -1
    @objc dynamic var name: String = ""

    convenience init(id: Int, name: String) {
        self.init()        
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
    }
}
```

My message object has a `recipients` property that will hold a list of users that this message should be sent to.  When a user receives the message, they'll acknowledge it and that user will then be added to the `acknowledgedBy` list on the message.  Each time a user is added to the `acknowledgedBy` list, I need to check to see if everyone who should have received the message has acknowledged it.  When that condition is met, I'll set the `fullyAcknowledged` property of the message to true.

To check if the message has been acknowledged by everyone, I know I could iterate through each user in `recipients` and then check if that user is also in the `acknowledgedBy` list.  I also thought that I could probably accomplish this via the following two-step process:

1. Compare the element count in `recipients` and `acknowledgedBy` to make sure that they're the same; if they are...
2. Sort both lists and then compare them to determine if they contain the same users

But I'm wondering if there's a more efficient way to determine that one list contains all the elements of another list (even if they're not in the same order)?

EDIT ----------

It looks like I might also be able to use Sets to make this determination like so:

```
let ackSet = Set(message.acknowledgedBy)
let recipientSet = Set(message.recipients)
let fullyAcknowledged = ackSet.isSubset(of: recipientSet)
```

Answer (score 0):

Sets is not a good option I think, imagine you have duplicates in one of the list then it's wrong option. I strongly advice to take a look at [Testing for equality in Realm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38868686/testing-for-equality-in-realm/38877533#38877533)

If `User` is unique, I'd use primaryKey https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/#primary-keys. Then when you will save your objects with identical ids no copy will be created => you can compare this objects `==` by default implementation of realm

If two different users can have the same ids, then I'd write my own method which will require equality of id & name. Then you can create dictionary with with `[String: Int]` so you might have the following code

```
var dict = [String: Int]()
message.acknowledgedBy.forEach { user in
  if let value = dict[user.name + "\(id)"] {
    dict[user.name + "\(id)"] = value + 1        
  } else {
    dict[user.name + "\(id)"] = 1
  }
}
let isMatched = message.recipients.reduce(true) { (reducedValue, user) in
  if let value = dict[user.name + "\(id)"] {
     dict[user.name + "\(id)"] = value - 1
     return (value - 1 >= 0) && reducedValue
  } else {
     return false
  }
}
```

It's quite rude implementation, but I think you will get the idea