# Comparing Objects Realm Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm, equatable

I'm trying to compare 2 Realm Objects in Swift.

```
// Object 1 Prints:

currentObject:  Optional(ObjectClass {
    order = 0;
    number = 010;
    temp = 903;
    state = 6;

})

// Object 2 Prints:

 lastObject:  Optional(ObjectClass {
        order = 0;
        number = 010;
        temp = 903;
        state = 6;

    })
```

Obviously the values are equal. But the Objects are not.

```
print(lastObject?.number == currentObject?.number) // Prints True
print(lastObject == currentObject) // Prints False
```

I tried to implement equatable in the object class. But Xcode isn't liking it due to Realm.

> Redundant conformance of 'ObjectClass' to protocol 'Equatable'

How can I compare the variables of lastObject to currentObject? I imagine theres a better way than checking each object's variable against each other. But I don't know what it is.

Object Class:

```
import UIKit
import RealmSwift

class ObjectClass: Object {

    @objc dynamic var order = 0
    @objc dynamic var number = ""
    @objc dynamic var temp = 0
    @objc dynamic var state = 1

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Realm objects already conform to Equatable and Hashable since they are subclasses of NSObject. The only thing you need to do is override the isEqual method:

```
import RealmSwift

class ObjectClass: Object {

    @objc dynamic var order = 0
    @objc dynamic var number = ""
    @objc dynamic var temp = 0
    @objc dynamic var state = 1

    override func isEqual(_ object: Any?) -> Bool {
        if let object = object as? ObjectClass {
            return self.order == object.order && self.number == object.number 
                   && self.temp == object.temp && self.state == object.state
        } else {
            return false
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @stonedstudio Maybe I am overlooking something but what does this answer have to do with conforming to being Equatable and Hashable? Isn't the isEqual function just comparing the objects variables against each other `self.order == object.order` which the OP already mentioned in the question *I imagine theres a better way than checking each object's variable against each other.*? There's no reason to override isEqual as it could be called 'func pizza(_ object: Any?) -> Bool' and get the same result and you still maintain the original isEqual functionality.

Comment: @Jay Realm I believe it's because Realm overrides equatable. And apparently doesn't care about the value of the objects: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38877533/4667835

Comment: @StonedStudio it does when the objects are unmanaged or managed but not one of each. Not sure why this is the accepted answer as this is what you said you didn't want to do *I imagine theres a better way than checking each object's variable against each other*. It's not a bad answer by any means, but it doesn't seem to match the question criteria. Well, glad you got something that worked either way :-)

Comment: Hey Jay, my understanding of the link is that Realm equatable only works when both are managed or unmanaged. And when checking managed objects, it's only checking if both objects point to the same spot in memory. But I could be wrong. - Your answer is the better way as it's an override of the class that lets you then use lastObject.isEqual(currentObject). - My temporary solution was using a swift statement with a very long tuple.

Comment: @StonedStudio My prior answer wasn't really clear so I've updated it and provided a much simpler solution, along with some explanation. Keeping in mind that this is an OBJECT comparison - as answered by this answer if you want to compare the variables, it just a straight forward comparison of those properties against each other.

Comment: Yep. Object match is what I was looking for. My temporary fix was just comparing the objects to make sure they matched by individually checking the variables

Comment: @StonedStudio If you are looking for an *object* match, this answer isn't correct as if you have two totally different objects that happen to have the same property values, this will show they are equal as it compares only properties. If you want an *object* match then you need to add a primary key and use the code in my answer.

Comment: I guess object match is not what I was looking for then. But rather if the objects had the same values.

Answer (score 0):

tl;dr

Change your object class to include a primary key and == will work to see if they are the same *object*. If they are the same object then their property variables will always be the same

```
class ObjectClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var object_id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var order = 0
    @objc dynamic var number = ""
    @objc dynamic var temp = 0
    @objc dynamic var state = 1

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
       return "object_id"
    }    
}
```

If you want to just compare the objects properties, then it's a straightforward property to property comparison (or implement isEqual and use == per the other answer)

**Discussion**

When comparing Realm objects we need to understand what we're comparing; are you looking too see if the objects properties have the same values or are you looking to see if they are the same objects?

If other words take a Realm object

```
class RealmObject: Object {
   @objc dynamic var text = ""
}
```

if two objects are created

```
let o0 = RealmObject()
o0.text = "Hello"

let o1 = RealmObject()
o1.text = "Hello"
```

and we compare the objects

```
print( o1 == o0 )
```

will print false because o0 and o1 are two separate objects.

Whereas if we compare a property

```
print( o0.text == o1.text )
```

would produce true because those properties are equal.

Along those same lines, after Realm 3.8 I believe you cannot test to see if two objects are the same using Equatable without a primary key. Check this out

```
let o0 = ObjectClass()
o0.order = 1

try! realm.write {
   realm.add(o0)
}
            
let o1 = realm.objects(ObjectClass.self).first!          
print( o1 == o0 ) //prints false  
print( o1.isSameObject(as: o0) ) //prints true
```

However, if we add a primary key to the ObjectClass

```
class ObjectClass: Object {
    @objc dynamic var object_id = UUID().uuidString
    @objc dynamic var order = 0

    override static func primaryKey() -> String? {
        return "object_id"
    }
}
```

and run the code again, they both print true

```
print( o1 == o0 ) //prints true  
print( o1.isSameObject(as: o0) ) //prints true
```

Comment: This was the first thing I tried and it didn't work. I created a new ObjectClass constant and then set it equal the variables equal to the variables of the Realm Object. It still printed not equal.

Comment: @StonedStudio Look at my example and code. It certainly works unless you're doing something different as that was copy and pasted directly from a working project.